# jQuery ajaxForm - Load Function after other Function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function that submit a form and starts an imageupload.
After the imageupload is complete, another function must be start.

```
$('#photoimg').on('change', function() {
    $("div.imguploadform").hide();
    $("#preview").html('<img src="loader48-2.gif" alt="Bild wird hochgeladen..." />');
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#preview'
    }).submit();
});
```

The following code must be start after the upload is finished.

```
$("#bildcheck").html('').load('imgfunction-bilderchk.php');
```

But where i must the function insert?

I hope someone can help me.

Best regards 
Hendrik

Comment: `ajaxForm()` has a completion callback.  See its documentation for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `success:`

> Callback function to be invoked after the form has been submitted.

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
    target: '#preview',
    success: function () {
        $("#bildcheck").html('').load('imgfunction-bilderchk.php');
    }
}).submit();
```

Read http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object

Comment: is it success or onSuccess?? See my answer to compare

Comment: A) if you're using a later version of jQuery, this should use .done/.fail/.always instead of success, but not a huge deal if you're using an older version.

B) You may want to set `async: false` when loading to ensure the ajax call is fully closed before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
    target: '#preview',
    onSuccess:function(){$("#bildcheck").html('').load('imgfunction-bilderchk.php');}
}).submit();
```

this should work.

Comment: Thank you too for your answer.